# Is the "protection" tag too broad?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of this posting, there are 3 questions using [the "protection" tag](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection).  They each describe a completely different aspect of protection: waterproofing, electrical-spike-proofing, and vibration-proofing.

I can envision a lot more questions in the form "how do I prevent X from happening to my robot" or "why do robots have X?" popping up here.  There is certainly enough good advice to give in mechanical, electrical, and software design for each of those areas to have their own version of the "protection" tag (eventually, anyway).

So my question is whether "protection" is the best all-inclusive term to use, or if are there more apt tags to direct people to questions concerning "how to prevent your robot from breaking itself".

Comment: I'm also curious about the relationship between "protection" in this sense, and protection _from_ the robot in the form of E-stops.  Is that a separate question or can we lump that in here?

Comment: This is meta, you can lump it in if you want :). I think that goes underneath [tag:safety]

Answer (score 2):

I think for now, it's OK. Tags are mainly for filtering--in this case, tag combinations do the trick. It's fine if a tag has subcategories.

We can always retag if the need appears later. Remember, tags get autodeleted in a few weeks if they are only on one question. Breaking [protection](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) up has the risk of the subtags getting deleted. Better to avoid that for now :)

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how much sensible built-in functionality SE sites come with that you never notice but without which the sites wouldn't be anywhere near as pleasant as they are

Comment: @ThomasH: Me either :)